# Collection.sort: 'cannot find symbol' despite giving right type, include, comperator

Tags: java, collections, cannot-find-symbol

I'm getting a cannot find symbol error when I try to compile my code. 
I checked all the standard answers, there is a comperator implemented, I included the stuff I use, I am giving the function the right type. 
So what am I missing?

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
class Planner implements MinSpanTree {

public List<Road> findCheapConversionPlan(List<Junction> junctions, List<Road> roads){
    Collection.sort(roads);
    return roads;
}
}
```

The road class includes this:

```
class Road implements Comparable<Road> {
@Override
public int compareTo(Road other){
    double diff=this.weight-other.getWeight();
    if (diff == 0) return 0;
    if (diff > 0) return 1;
    return -1;
}

public int compare(Road x, Road y){
    double diff=x.getWeight()-y.getWeight();
    if (diff == 0) return 0;
    if (diff > 0) return 1;
    return -1;
}
}
```

Every time I try to compile the Planner.java class, I get the same error:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
Planner.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        Collection.sort(roads);
                  ^
  symbol:   method sort(List<Road>)
  location: interface Collection
1 error
```

My javac version is javac 1.7.0_79.
According to [the oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) Collection.sort should be implemented at least since 1.6.

Comment: Your own link indicates it's `Collections.sort` (plural), not `Collection.sort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the `s` from the Helper Methods `Collections` for the `Collection` Interface:

```
Collections.sort
```

Answer (score 1):

The [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) you referenced is of the `Collections` class. Not `Collection`